# Jquery Jtable - Show records with many-to-one attributes (Spring-Hibernate)

Tags: java, jquery, spring, hibernate, jquery-jtable

I'm stuck with the following...

I have this objects, using hibernate and spring:

```
public class Employee
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    String id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city")
    City city;

     //gets and sets...
}
```

and this..

```
public class City
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   String id;
   @Column(name = "name")
   String city;

   //gets and sets...
}
```

I need to show the employee records with jTable. I'm doing this:

```
$('#empleados').jtable(
{
   title: 'Employees',
   sorting: true,
   selecting: true,
   actions: 
   {
      listAction: 'getEmployeesTable',
      createAction: 'addEmployee',
      updateAction: 'updateEmployess',
      deleteAction: 'deleteEmployee'
   },
fields: {
id:{
key: true,
list: false

},

name: {
title: "Name"
},
city: {
title: "City",
options: "getCities",
display:function(data){
return data.record.city.name;
}

}
}

}
});
```

I'm seeing the column City value and the combo values on create and edit form correctly, but when I want to Save or Update a record, I have an error because of the mapping between the city name and the city object.
I found examples but putting only the id's of the many-to-one attribute, but not the entire object.

Comment: Please post your Error Stacktrace.

Comment: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.persistence.City' for property 'city'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.persistence.City] for property 'city': no matching editors or conversion strategy found Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Editar registroclose

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class Employee
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    City city;
}

public class City
{
   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "city_id")
   Long id;
   @Column(name = "city_name")
   String city;

   //gets and sets...
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the same message error. =(
I think the problem is because on the POST data the city Attribute sended is only the id and not the id and the name.

Comment: Please could you show more infos like your post request, repository interface, service class ?